# Query table when variable can be null

Tags: java, sql

I have 3 variables which values are inserted by the user.

I need to query a table with 3 columns and if one on the variables is null not to execute query.

How do I do that without if-else?

```
String par1= request.getParameter("par1");
String par2= request.getParameter("par2");
String par3= request.getParameter("par3 ");

String query = "select * from table t " +
                "where t.var1 = ? " + 
                    "and t.var2" +
                    "and t.var3= ? ";

Connection conn = DataBase.getConnection();
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
s.setString(1, par1);
s.setString(2, par2);
s.setString(3, par3);
```

EDIT - let me be more clear

[image: no]

I want to query a search, where the user can chose which fields to fill(some of them can stay empty ).

What it the propare way of doing so?

Comment: Whats wrong with a `null` check in `if` ?

Comment: you want to check a condition without using a conditional?  Why?

Comment: What is wrong with an if-else statement here?? What is your reason for not using it????

Comment: because that is the whole perpose of what i was asking. if the variable is null i dont want to query him (This is a search option which contains of 3 textboxes, and the user can chose which textboxes to query from). if someone can give me an example of a solution i will be glad to see how this is possible.

Comment: How about binding a wildcard when the parameter is null?  That would save you from building the SQL up, and then having weird binding rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way around conditionals here. You need to use a `StringBuilder` along with the `if-else` blocks to build your `SELECT` query dynamically here.

```
String par1 = "par1"; // intialized for testing
String par2 = null;
String par3 = "par3";

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select * from table t");

if (par1 != null || par2 != null || par3 != null) {
    query.append(" where ");
    if (par1 != null) {
        query.append("t.var1 = ?");
    }
    if (par2 != null) {
        if (par1 != null) {
            query.append(" AND ");
        }
        query.append("t.var2 = ?");
    }
    if (par3 != null) {
        if (par1 != null || par2 != null) {
            query.append(" AND ");
        }
        query.append("t.var3 = ?");
    }
}

System.out.println(query);
```

***Output** :*

```
select * from table t where t.var1 = ? AND t.var3 = ?
```

Please, note that you'd have to bind your placeholder values conditionally too.

```
Connection conn = DataBase.getConnection();
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());

if (par1 != null || par2 != null || par3 != null) {
    int n = 1;
    if (par1 != null) {
        s.setString(n++, par1);
    }
    if (par2 != null) {
        s.setString(n++, par2);
    }
    if (par3 != null) {
        s.setString(n, par3);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like there has to be a better way , but this should work i will try it.

Comment: Yea Exactly , I was troubled with the binding part, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

User ternary operator [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a)

Sample code:

```
String x = null;
String y = x!=null ? "Its not null" : "It is null"
```

Your code

```
String par1= request.getParameter("par1")==null? "" :
                                               request.getParameter("par1");
```

Comment: but again , in this situation i will still be quering if t.var = "", and that is not what i need..

Comment: @susparsy then I think there is no way out. I don't understand why not to use `IF`. Because its invented for this purpose only.

Comment: That is just a hidden if... :)

Answer (score 0):

If using **ugliness** counts as "without if-else":

```
String[] fields = {"par1","par2","par3"};

String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE t ";
String where = "";

String[] whereString = new String[]{" WHERE ", " AND "};

int whereAddress = 0;

List<String> valuesAsParameters = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String fieldName : fields) {
   String value = request.getParameter(fieldName);

   //do we need WHERE or AND?
   where += whereString[whereAddress];
   whereAddress=1; //change state

   where += fieldName;


   //should not EVER use exception for control flow... Outside of assignments, that is
   try {
     //throws NPE **on purpose**... Yuck!!!
     valuesAsParameters.add(value.toString());
     // to check emptiness of string, we could use value.charAt(0) for the same purpose
     where += " = ? ";
   } catch(NullPointerException e) { 
     // EEEEEEKKKK! No, please really, don't do stuff like this... 
     // I shall burn in hell for even 
     // thinking about 
     //      **thinking about** 
     //           ****thinking about**** 
     // something this unexplainably, and universally bad...
     where += " IS NULL ";
   }

}

Connection conn = DataBase.getConnection();
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
int i=1;
for(String value : valuesAsParameters) {
  s.setString(i++, value);
}
```

Excuse me, I have to go and vomit now... This code is pure evilness. **Here be dragons** Don't do this at home. And by **home** I mean the known *and the **unnknown** parts* of the Universe too. Including *unknown dimensions*, places that don't exist, and even dreams... <sub>I think</sub> <sup>I</sup> already sta<sub>rted</sub> t<sup>o</sup> see wobbbly th<sup>ings...</sup>

**EDIT**

Ok, much better now. However, the code above does not do what OP wants, though easy to tailor it to that. What this does is uses IS NULL clause for null values, as in SQL, that is the way of comparing something to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding wildcards when the parameters are null?  This would effectively exclude them from the query without having to build up the query with a `StringBuilder` and then keep track of how you're binding.

```
String query = "select * from table t " +
                "where t.var1 like ? " + 
                    "and t.var2 like ?" +
                    "and t.var3 like ? ";

Connection conn = DataBase.getConnection();
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
s.setString(1, par1 != null ? par1 : "%");
s.setString(2, par2 != null ? par2 : "%");
s.setString(3, par3 != null ? par3 : "%");
```

Comment: intresting, i tought about it, i should try that